# Large SWT Image is not printed properly

Tags: printing, swt, eclipse-rcp

Hei, SWT Gurus, I have a pretty weird situation. The thing is, that I am trying to print gantt chart in my Eclipse RCP application. Gantt chart is quite long and sometimes high as well. Its dimensions are following: height=3008px (2 vertical pages), width > 20000px. My print area can fit something like 1400x2000 px. First of all, I am creating image out with my chart (image is OK, I can save it separately and see, that everything is there). However, in order to print it on the paper, I am printing it piece by piece (moving source X and Y positions respectively). This algorithm was working fine for some time, but now something strange happened:

When chart is not high enough and can fit on 1 vertical page, then it is printed normally, but when it is 2 vertical pages, then only second vertical page is printed and first one is left out. There are no errors, nor anything, that could help me. I thought, may be there is not enough heap memory, so I allocated -Xmx1014m space to my application, but it didn't helped. So, I am really lost, and can not find any solution or even an explanation to this problem. I was trying to simply print image by gc.drwImage(image, x, y), but is also printed me only the second half of it. I am also printing some text after every try of printing an image, and it is printed

The code, that is responsible for printing an image is following:

```
for (int verticalPageNumber = 0; verticalPageNumber <= pageCount.vGanttChartPagesCount; verticalPageNumber++) {
        // horizontal position needs to be reset to 0 before printing next bunch of horizontal pages

        int imgPieceSrcX = 0;
        for (int horizontalPageNumber = 0; horizontalPageNumber <= pageCount.hGanttChartPagesCount; horizontalPageNumber++) {

            // Calculate bounds for the next page
            final Rectangle printBounds = PrintingUtils.calculatePrintBounds(printerClientArea, scaleFactor, verticalPageNumber, horizontalPageNumber);

            if (shouldPrint(printer.getPrinterData(), currentPageNr)
                  && nextPageHasSomethingToPrint(imgPieceSrcX, imgPieceSrcY, totalGanttChartArea.width, totalGanttChartArea.height)) {
                printer.startPage();

                final Transform printerTransform = PrintingUtils.setUpTransform(printer, printerClientArea, scaleFactor, gc, printBounds);

                printHeader(gc, currentPageNr, printBounds);

                imgPieceSrcY = printBounds.y;

                final int imgPieceSrcHeight =
                      imgPieceSrcY + printBounds.height < ganttChartImage.getBounds().height ? printBounds.height : ganttChartImage.getBounds().height
                            - imgPieceSrcY;

                final int imgPieceSrcWidth =
                      imgPieceSrcX + printBounds.width < ganttChartImage.getBounds().width ? printBounds.width : ganttChartImage.getBounds().width
                            - imgPieceSrcX;

                if (imgPieceSrcHeight > 0 && imgPieceSrcWidth > 0) {
                    // gantt chart is printed as image, piece by piece
                    gc.drawImage(ganttChartImage,
                          imgPieceSrcX, imgPieceSrcY,
                          imgPieceSrcWidth, imgPieceSrcHeight,
                          printBounds.x, printBounds.y,
                          imgPieceSrcWidth, imgPieceSrcHeight); // destination width and height equal to source width and height to prevent
                    // stretching/shrinking of image
                    // move x and y to print next image piece

                    gc.drawText("Text " + currentPageNr, imgPieceSrcX, imgPieceSrcY);

                    imgPieceSrcX += printBounds.width;

                }

                currentPageNr++;

                printer.endPage();
                printerTransform.dispose();
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just found out, that if I will put instead of imgPieceSrcWidth and imgPieceSrcHeight in destination area, not more the 600px, then image is shrinked but printed! However, if I put 700px there (and my imgPieceSrcWidth and imgPieceSrcHeight are usually more, then 600), then it is not printed. Any ideas?

Comment: Can it be some kind of a cash for images, or something like that, which I could clean or at least investigate further, since just now without any modifications the same image was printed normally and then again failed to print normally? :(

Comment: Ok, It was pretty weird situation, since it just started working normally. May be there is something to deal with not disposing image objects, or some other OS resources, after printing was finished? Still don't understand...